# Neo4j write performance degradation

Tags: java, neo4j

I have been trying neo4j-2.1.2 enterprise evaluation version in my application for a while. I have heard of neo4j's immense capacity to insert 1 million nodes in a matter of few seconds. Enamored by such touting, I have decided to see it in action. Initially, it took 4 seconds to insert 10,000 nodes. As the number of nodes in the graph database increased, I started to witness some degradation in write performance. It started taking 60 seconds for inserting 60,000 nodes and the time increased exponentially. I am not able to find out the reason behind this degradation. I tried googling but there is not much information I can find.

Specifications are as follows:

```
* Application heap = 10 GB      
* ConcurrentMaxSweep GC     
* Neo4J cache type = hpc    
* Each node will have at most 4 properties     
* uniqueKey property on the node is indexed.
* Everything else in neo4j properties left to default
* 8 core processor machine.
```

Can somebody guide me in solving this performance issue?? I am using java core API for creating nodes.

**Update**
Please find my code below

```
public class GraphDatabaseManager
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GraphDatabaseManager.class);

    private GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    private Index<org.neo4j.graphdb.Node> nodeIndex;
    private UniqueFactory<org.neo4j.graphdb.Node> factory;
    private Index<org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship> relationShipIndex;

    private static final String PROPERTY_FILE = "conf" + File.separator + "graphDB" + File.separator + "Neo4j.properties";

    private static final String UNIQUE_KEY = GraphEntity.UNIQUE_KEY;
    private static final String NODES = "nodes";
    private static final String RELATIONSHIPS = "relationships";

    private void init(Map<String, String> props)
    {
        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(props.remove(GraphDBManager.DB_PATH))
                .loadPropertiesFromFile(PROPERTY_FILE)
                .setConfig(ShellSettings.remote_shell_enabled, props.get(GraphDBManager.REMOTE_SHELL_ENABLED))
                .setConfig(ShellSettings.remote_shell_host, props.get(GraphDBManager.REMOTE_SHELL_HOST))
                .setConfig(ShellSettings.remote_shell_port, props.get(GraphDBManager.REMOTE_SHELL_PORT))
                .setConfig(ShellSettings.remote_shell_read_only, props.get(GraphDBManager.REMOTE_SHELL_READ_ONLY)).newGraphDatabase();

        Transaction transaction = graphDb.beginTx();
        nodeIndex = graphDb.index().forNodes(NODES);

        factory = new UniqueNodeFactory(graphDb, NODES)
        {
            @Override
            protected void initialize(org.neo4j.graphdb.Node node, Map<String, Object> props)
            {
            }
        };
        relationShipIndex = graphDb.index().forRelationships(RELATIONSHIPS);
        transaction.success();
        transaction.close();
    }

    public <T extends Node> void createNodes(List<T> nodes) throws Exception
    {
        if (CommonUtils.isCollectionNullOrEmpty(nodes))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nodes cannot be Empty while Creating");

        List<List<T>> nodeLists = CommonUtils.split(nodes, getNodeBatchSize());
        for (List<T> list : nodeLists)
        {
            try
            {
                createOrUpdateNodes0(list, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    private Integer getNodeBatchSize()
    {
        return Integer.getInteger("NODES_BATCH_SIZE", 1000);
    }

    private void createOrUpdateNodes0(List<? extends Node> nodes, boolean isCreate) throws Exception
    {
        org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction transaction = graphDb.beginTx();

        try
        {
            for (Node node : nodes)
            {
                if (node == null)
                    continue;

                saveOrUpdateNode(node, isCreate);
            }
            transaction.success();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            transaction.failure();
            throw new Exception("Exception while storing nodes for ", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            transaction.close();
        }
    }

    protected void saveOrUpdateNode(Node node, boolean isCreate) throws Exception
    {
        String uniqueKey = node.getUniqueKey();
        try
        {

            org.neo4j.graphdb.Node neoNode = null;

            boolean isNodeExist = isNodeExist(uniqueKey);

            if (isCreate)
            {

                if (isNodeExist)
                {
                    if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
                        logger.trace(" Node already Exists.....Returning the same..." + node);
                    return;
                }

                neoNode = factory.getOrCreate(UNIQUE_KEY, uniqueKey);
                nodeIndex.add(neoNode, UNIQUE_KEY, uniqueKey);

                if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
                    logger.trace("  NeoNode created Successfully..." + uniqueKey);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!isNodeExist)
                    return;
                neoNode = getNeoNode(uniqueKey);
            }

            for (Entry<String, Object> neoProps : node.getProperties().entrySet())
            {
                if (neoProps.getValue() != null)
                    neoNode.setProperty(neoProps.getKey(), neoProps.getValue());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception while creating NeoNode with Unique key " + uniqueKey, e);
        }
    }

    protected boolean isNodeExist(String uniqueKey)
    {
        return nodeIndex.get(UNIQUE_KEY, uniqueKey).hasNext();
    }

    protected void addNodeIndex(Node node, String column, Object value)
    {
        org.neo4j.graphdb.Node neoNode = getNeoNode(node.getUniqueKey());
        nodeIndex.add(neoNode, column, value);
    }

    private org.neo4j.graphdb.Node getNeoNode(String uniqueKey)
    {
        return (uniqueKey != null) ? nodeIndex.get(UNIQUE_KEY, uniqueKey).getSingle() : null;
    }

    public <T extends Relationship> void createRelationships(List<T> relationships) throws Exception
    {

        if (CommonUtils.isCollectionNullOrEmpty(relationships))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Relationships cannot be Empty while Creating");

        List<List<T>> relationshipLists = CommonUtils.split(relationships, getRelationBatchSize());
        for (List<T> relationshiplist : relationshipLists)
        {
            try
            {
                createOrUpdateRelationships0(relationshiplist, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    private Integer getRelationBatchSize()
    {
        return Integer.getInteger("RELATIONSHIP_BATCH_SIZE", 1000);
    }

    private void createOrUpdateRelationships0(List<? extends Relationship> relationShips, boolean isCreate) throws Exception
    {
        org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction transaction = graphDb.beginTx();
        try
        {
            for (Relationship relationship : relationShips)
            {
                if (relationship == null)
                    continue;

                saveOrUpdateRelationship(relationship, isCreate);

                Entity relationshipEntity = GraphObjectManager.getRelationshipClz(relationship.getType());

                if (relationshipEntity == null)
                    throw new Exception(" Could not find Entity for relationShip :: " + relationship.getType());

                Indexedcolumns indexedcolumns = relationshipEntity.getIndexedcolumns();
                if (indexedcolumns != null)
                {
                    for (String index : indexedcolumns.getIndex())
                    {
                        Object value = relationship.getProperty(index);
                        addRelationshipIndex(relationship, index, value);
                    }
                }
            }
            transaction.success();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            transaction.failure();
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            transaction.close();
        }
    }

    protected void saveOrUpdateRelationship(Relationship relationShip, boolean isCreate) throws Exception
    {
        String uniqueKey = relationShip.getUniqueKey();
        try
        {
            org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship neoRelationShip = null;
            boolean isRelationshipExist = isRelationshipExist(uniqueKey);
            if (isCreate)
            {

                if (isRelationshipExist)
                {
                    if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
                        logger.trace(" RelationShip already Exists.....Returning the same..." + relationShip);
                    return;
                }

                org.neo4j.graphdb.Node neoStartNode = getNeoNode(relationShip.getStartNodeUniqueKey());
                org.neo4j.graphdb.Node neoEndNode = getNeoNode(relationShip.getEndNodeUniqueKey());

                validateRelationshipNodes(relationShip, neoStartNode, neoEndNode);

                neoRelationShip = neoStartNode.createRelationshipTo(neoEndNode, new Neo4jRelationshipType(relationShip.getType()));

                relationShipIndex.add(neoRelationShip, UNIQUE_KEY, uniqueKey);

                if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
                    logger.trace("  NeoRelationship created Successfully..." + uniqueKey);

            }
            else
            {
                if (!isRelationshipExist)
                    return;
                neoRelationShip = getNeoRelationship(uniqueKey);
            }

            for (Entry<String, Object> relProps : relationShip.getProperties().entrySet())
            {
                if (relProps.getValue() == null)
                    continue;
                neoRelationShip.setProperty(relProps.getKey(), relProps.getValue());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception while creating NeoRelationShip with Unique key " + relationShip.getUniqueKey(), e);
        }
    }

    protected boolean isRelationshipExist(String uniqueKey)
    {
        return relationShipIndex.get(UNIQUE_KEY, uniqueKey).hasNext();
    }

    private org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship getNeoRelationship(String uniqueKey)
    {
        return (uniqueKey != null) ? relationShipIndex.get(UNIQUE_KEY, uniqueKey).getSingle() : null;
    }

    private void validateRelationshipNodes(Relationship relationShip, org.neo4j.graphdb.Node neoStartNode, org.neo4j.graphdb.Node neoEndNode)
            throws Exception
    {
        if (neoStartNode == null && neoEndNode == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Start Node and End Node is not present in DB " + "for relationship " + relationShip);
        }
        else if (neoStartNode == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Start Node is not present in DB " + "for relationship " + relationShip);
        }
        else if (neoEndNode == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("End Node is not present in DB " + "for relationship " + relationShip);
        }
    }

    protected void addRelationshipIndex(Relationship relationship, String column, Object value)
    {
        org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship neoRelationship = getNeoRelationship(relationship.getUniqueKey());
        relationShipIndex.add(neoRelationship, column, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: please share the code doing the import

Comment: Take a look at: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/performance-guide.html#_write_performance

Comment: share the import code. basically i believe you are not simply creating new nodes, but doing some unoptimized logic before creation - like matching relations to other nodes - thus the more nodes you have already created, the more time it takes for a new node to create, since it must first calculate the logic on all previous nodes

Comment: Aside from agreeing that you need to share the import code, there are many other considerations here. Are you using labels? Legacy indexes? Have you set up any uniqueness constraints? How are you ingesting the raw data that you're inserting (in big batches or one by one)?  Are you using the Neo API to create these nodes or Cypher CREATE/MERGE?   Throw us a frickin' bone here!

Comment: Neo4j can import 1M nodes per second in non-transaction batch insertion mode. Check out the batch-inserter API, you probably want to take care of uniqueness in an upfront pass.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Could you give more words on the non-tx batch insertion mode? I get the write performance too.